# Detect scroll end for a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with position `fixed` and `top:96.9%`. I need to handle this `div` when the page reaches its end *(i.e when the page cannot be scrolled down further)*. How could I detect if the page scroll has reached its end? I did this:

```
if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == $(document).height()) {
   // No more scroll!
}
```

Is there a better way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

`var pixelsBelow = $(window).scrollHeight - $(window).clientHeight - $(window).scrollTop;
if (pixelsBelow > 10) ...`

10 is a slop factor; you'll generally want to trigger the "at bottom" event even if there are still a few pixels unseen.